# Confusion regarding splitting of the s2 heart sound

Tags: cardiac-physiology

I recently read that during inspiration the negative pressure in the thoracic cavity leads to increased venous return to the right atrium. This leads to late closure of the pulmonary valve as the extra blood that came in is pushed out by the right ventricle. So here’s the confusion, aren’t the AV valves closed during the entire ventricular systole? I mean the pressure in the ventricles during the systole is quite higher than that of the atria so how does this suctioned blood (during inspiration) reaches the right ventricle when the AV valve is closed? It opens I perfectly remember, only after the isovolumetric relaxation of the ventricles. Am I missing something?

Link from the stanford university: https://stanfordmedicine25.stanford.edu/the25/cardiac.html

Also the excerpt: “Additionally, during inspiration, more blood fills the right ventricle leading to a slightly longer ejection time, adding to the delayed pulmonic valve closure.”

How is this possible?

Comment: "Aren’t the AV valves closed during the entire ventricular systole?" -- What do you mean by AV valves? Do you mean the tricuspid valve?

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, AV means Atrioventricular valves, here the tricuspid valve. The source is an osmosis video but the splitting is also mentioned in Harrison’s, not with the explanation but just the mention. Here : (FIGURE 38-8 Top. Normal physiologic splitting. During expiration, the aortic (A2) and pulmonic (P2) components of the second heart sound are separated by <30 ms and are appreciated as a single sound. During inspiration, the splitting interval widens, and A2 and P2 are clearly separated into two distinct sounds.) Ch 38, fig 38.8 Pg 247 Harrison’s 20th edition

Comment: You write "I recently read that during inspiration the negative pressure in the thoracic cavity leads to increased venous return to the right atrium"; the source you link writes "Additionally, during inspiration, more blood fills the right ventricle"; I think the link between those statements explains the gap you're asking about, though I'm not particularly familiar with this aspect of cardiac physiology.

Comment: @BryanKrause They literally mean the same thing. Venous return is the systemic blood the vena cavae carry to the right atrium. Blood then goes into the ventricles. Although when the A-V valve is open the blood then can directly FLOW into the ventricles through the atria, passively i.e. not having to be stored there first. But that’s my question, how will the systemic blood flow into the right ventricle if the tricuspid valve doesn’t open up until the pressure in the atria exceeds the pressure in the ventricles. And it doesn’t until the isovolumetric relaxation of ventricles is completed.

Comment: Splitting Of S2 does not occur only due to negative intrathoracic pressure. It also occurs due to decreased resistance in pulmonary circuit during inspiration. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK341/#_NBK341_pubdet_  Moreover inspiration need not only occur during isovolumic contraction, it can also occur during ventricular filling. Even if it occurs during contraction atrial filling will be increased which can then go to ventricles during relaxation.

Comment: @AaishaAussie My point is that your question takes as given "more blood in atrium", and then wonders why this would affect something related to the ventricle if the tricuspid is closed. But...per my comment, and your source, you should be expecting more blood in the ventricle, too.

Answer (score 4):

The respiratory and cardiac cycles vary in length. While the average adult respiratory rate is between 12-20 breaths per minute, the heart beats at an average of 60-100 bpm. During a single respiratory cycle (inspiration plus expiration), a person will complete several cardiac cycles. As such, during inspiration, while the blood **immediately** enters the RA, it **also** flows into the RV and then into the PA **within the same respiratory cycle**.

(In addition, vascular resistance in the PA is decreased during inspiration, thus allowing for even greater volumes of blood to flow across the pulmonic valve and subsequently delay the P2 heart sound further.)

This chart might help illustrate the point.

> A chart depicting the motion of cardiac and respiratory series for 40
> phantoms with 5 cardiac and 1 respiratory cycle from end-inhalation to
> exhalation.

[image: A chart depicting the motion of cardiac and respiratory series for 40 phantoms with 5 cardiac and 1 respiratory cycle from end-inhalation to exhalation.]

Chart Source:
Huh Y, Shrestha U, Gullberg GT, Seo Y. Monte Carlo Simulation and Reconstruction: Assessment of Myocardial Perfusion Imaging of Tracer Dynamics With Cardiac Motion Due to Deformation and Respiration Using Gamma Camera With Continuous Acquisition. *Frontiers in Cardiovascular Medicine.* 2022;9. doi:https://doi.org/10.3389/fcvm.2022.871967

Answer (score 2):

To address your two questions:

1. **How does the ‘suctioned’ blood during inspiration reach the Right Ventricle ( RV)  as the Tricuspid Atrioventricular  Valve is shut during ventricular systole.**

Yes, the Atrio-Ventricular valves (including the tricuspid) are closed during ventricular systole and any of the ‘suctioned’ blood arriving into the right atrium while the tricuspid valve is closed is simply stored in the Right Atrium until the moment the tricuspid valve  opens when this  blood is  propelled into the Right Ventricle

2. **During inspiration more blood fills the RV leading to a slightly longer ejection time adding to delayed Pulmonary Valve closure.How is this possible?**

There are two separate effects at work here:

First : Ventricular ejection time to is proportional to the volume of blood being expelled. So the ejection of more blood (greater volume)  would take longer than ejecting less blood (less volume). Right Ventricular volume in *inspiration* exceeds Right ventricular volume in *expiration* on account of increased venous return- due to the ‘suctioned’ blood you refer to in your question. So now ,the ejection time required to eject this larger volume of blood  will correspondingly  be greater in inspiration than expiration. Therefore, pulmonary valve closure is delayed.

A Second effect is the outflow of blood from the vetnricles into pulmonary and systemic circulation depends on a physical property of the vessels the **vascualr impedance** which is lower in the pulomonary ciruclation leading to prolonged outflow compared to systemic circulation and hence delayed Pulmonary valve closure compared to aortic valve closure.

This is of course applicable to *normal physiology* in the abscence of *pathology* which would have further modifying effects.